# Conditional Probabilty male students

Tags: probability, probability-theory

At a certain university, 30% of the students major in zoology. Of the students majoring in zoology, 60% are males. Of all the students at the university, 70% are males. What percentage of the all students at this university are males majoring in zoology?

I tried to get the solution for this question, by calculating:

> (0.3 * 0.6) / 0.7 = 0.2571

But the right answer seems to be 18%.

**why?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let there be $100$ students in the university. Then there will be $30$ majoring in zoology. Of those $30$ students, there will be $0.6*30$ or $18$ males. Therefore the answer is $\frac{18}{100}$ or $0.18$

Answer (score 3):

$$P(A\cap B)=P(A|B)\cdot P(B)$$
In your case,
$$A=\text{is male}$$
$$B=\text{is majoring in zoology}$$
so
$$P(A\cap B)=(0.6)(0.3)=0.18$$

---

Notice that
$$ P(A|B)\cdot P(B) = P(B|A)\cdot P(A)$$
and so
$$ P(B|A) = \frac{P(A|B)\cdot P(B)}{P(A)} = \frac{(0.6)(0.3)}{0.7}=0.2571$$

This is the probability that a student at the university is majoring in zoology *given* that they are male.  This is not the same as the probability that they are majoring in zoology *and* that they are male.

In the first case, we move all of the males in the university into a big auditorium.  We then choose one of them at random, and consider the probability that he is a zoology major.

In the second case (which corresponds to your question), we move all of the male *and* female students into a big auditorium.  We the choose one of them at random, and consider the probability that s/he is a male zoology major.

Answer (score 3):

To see why this is wrong, take for example, $100$ students in the university. $30$ of them are doing zoology, $18$ of those being male. Can you see why the fact that 70 students are male is unnecessary here? Therefore, you should not be dividing by $0.7$.

What you should do is multiply the probability of being a zoology student with the probability of being a male knowing that the student is a zoology student.
So our probability $p$ is given by:

$p = P(M\cap Z)=P(M|Z)\cdot P(Z) = 0.6 \times 0.3$, with:

$M : $ being a male,

$Z$: being a zoology student.